# How to print outputs of different loops in one line, separated by a space?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the output of these two loops in the same line, separated by a space.

```
number = int(input())
words = []
for y in range(0, number, 1):
    word = str(input())
    words.append(word)
for i in range(0, len(word), 2):
    print(word[i], end='')
for t in range(1, len(word), 2):
        print(word[t], end='')
```

If I enter the word 'code', I get `cdoe`, when I actually want `cd oe`.

Comment: just add additional print between the `for` loops printing empty space

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri tried that, I get a new line between the outputs instead of a space.

Comment: @sacul doing that I get `c d\n o e`

Comment: did you tried printing like `print(' ', end='')`

Comment: That worked! I don't understand why, though. Could you explain? What does the `end=''` do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#print
Documentation link says the the end parameter is put to the output stream whenever the print function is called. The default value is `'\n'` which is a newline so by making it `''` it doesn't put any other character to the stream.